# Out of Memory Exception when dealing with duplicate data using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

When I try to fetch the data that that has duplicate record as shown in the relation below I get out of memory error in my test server. In the relation shown below I have duplicated records for supportingApplications.My test server has less memory space compared to that of the development and production. When I run the application in devleopment or produciton it picks one supporting application randomly without any issue.When I delete the record that are duplicated it works fine. Is something in hibernate that creates memory spike and how can I deal with such scenario?

```
class MainApplication{
@Column(name="main_app_id")
    int mainAppId;

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    List<Address> address ;
}

class SupportingApplication{
    int supportingAppId;

    //defining the relation

    @Column(name="main_app_id")
    int mainAppId

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="main_app_id", referencedColumnName="main_app_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private MainApplication mainApplication;

    String city;
    String state;   
}
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to suggest the following link so you can improve the mapping and maybe even solve this issue on your own: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: stackoverflows tend to create memory spikes, i am not sure, why it works on dev/prod, but in any case: Why is `SupportingApplication.main_app_id` not unique? (why/what for duplicates?) ...maybe you want/mean a `@ManyToOne`??

Comment: ...and "as scenario" it makes more sense (to me), that a "main app" has multiple (and not only one) "supporting apps"...!?

Comment: @xerx593 One application can only have one supporting documents. Since I am working on system that was alreadybuilt I did not make any changes to relations between the table. I think since dev and prod has more free memory it worked fine.

Comment: ..then consider to introduce & maintain a unique constraint on that column (on test, but also on all instances)

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue had to do with the server setting rather than the memory utilization. I increased the memory allocated for the server and everything worked fine.